# Xamarin, POST Request: image from gallery to api call

Tags: c#, android, post, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to upload an image with a POST request with an API call.
Getting the image from the gallery works. By using:

```
        StartActivityForResult(
        Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
```

With that, I receive an intent with different paths like: 
EncodedSchemeSpecificPart,
EncodedPath,
Path, etc.

I've tested the API call with POSTMAN, as form-data that has a file with the keyname file and also an auth-token inside the header. This works.

Now my question is, how do I add a file(image) in a POST call with C#?
This is what I have so far:

```
    try
    {
        Uri url = new Uri(basePath + "/pictures");
        HttpWebRequest request = 
        (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("auth-token", accesstoken);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
```

edit: the backend code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFile(@HeaderParam("Auth-Token") String token,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart body) throws RequestException {

    secure(token, "*");

    // Get the user data using the entity manager
    String subtype = body.getMediaType().getSubtype();

    switch(subtype) {
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg":
    case "png":
        break;
    default:
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

    String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + subtype;
    String uploadedFileLocation = context.getRealPath("/images/"+imageName);


    Picture picture = pictureService.createPictureReference(uploadedFileLocation);

    // Store the file
    try {
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        // If the file is stored
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(picture).build();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: what does the signature of the API call look like?

Comment: @Jason Sorry, I don't know what you mean with signature, can you give me an example?

Comment: A method signature is the list of Params and their types, etc.  ie, what the API docs tell you

Comment: @Jason I see, I think it's auth-token - string,
file - InputStream.

This is the code:
https://hastebin.com/egocayogod.scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `StartActivityForResult` using an intent that returns the chosen image so you can obtain a stream from

#### `StartActivityForResult` (Image picker/gallery)

```
using (var intent = new Intent())
{
    intent.SetType("image/*");
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Image To Upload"), PickImage);
}
```

Now in your `OnActivityResult` you can use the `ContentResolver` to obtain a stream from the picked image that you can `Post` as binary (`octet-stream`) or convert it to base64 (`application/json`) to match your `MultipartFormDataContent` API/Post requirements.

Note: Using Jersey?, as I am not sure how to interpret the InputStream vs FormDataBodyPart params when using json, is the InputStream in base64?

#### `OnActivityResult` and `HttpClient` Post w/ `StreamContent`

```
const string url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/image";
AndroidClientHandler handler;
HttpClient client;
protected async override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    string access_token = "some oauth2 token";

    if (resultCode.HasFlag(Result.Ok) && requestCode == PickImage)
    {
        using (var imageStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data))
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                handler = handler ?? new AndroidClientHandler();
                client = client ?? new HttpClient(handler);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth2", access_token);
                if (!client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Accept"))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                        .Accept
                        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                }
                using (var content = new StreamContent(imageStream))
                using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
                {
                    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post: {response.StatusCode} : {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}");
                }
            }).ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post: {task.Status}");
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post Faulted: {task.Exception.Message}");
                    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post Faulted: {task.Exception?.InnerException.Message}");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

Based upon needing to post something like this:

```
POST /pictures HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:60000
auth-token: some_token_here
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foobar.png"
Content-Type: image/png
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

#### MultipartFormDataContent with image content:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    handler = handler ?? new AndroidClientHandler();
    client = client ?? new HttpClient(handler);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("auth-token", access_token);

    using (var imageStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data))
    using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(imageStream))
    using (var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
    using (var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formDataContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "file", "DummyFileName.NotUsedOnServer");
        foreach (var content in formDataContent)
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentResolver.GetType(data.Data));
            break;
        }
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formDataContent))
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post: {response.StatusCode} : {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}");
        }
    }
}).ContinueWith((task) =>
{
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Post: {task.Status}");
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        Log.Error(TAG, $"Post Faulted: {task.Exception.Message}");
        Log.Error(TAG, $"Post Faulted: {task.Exception?.InnerException.Message}");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I have some issues and a question. First I send a token with the key "auth-token". So, it's not oauth2 in my case right? How would I add this auth-token value as header?

Next, I'm getting: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property ''ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Uri)" 
on line: 
                using (var imageStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data))

Last, The name 'PickImage' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I've changed it to " && requestCode == 0", is this correct? So, It's because I have this method inside a fragment, I get the "does not exist in the current context" error? Do I have to move the code to an Activity or can I use something like a cast? Thanks

Comment: It logs this: 12-10 14:03:07.443 D/TAG SUCCES( 7211): Post: UnsupportedMediaType : False
12-10 14:03:07.444 D/TAG SUCCES( 7211): Post: RanToCompletion.
But, there where no images added to the server/database.

Comment: Could it be that I have to give the content the key "file"?

Comment: Because nothing happens only the logs are displayed and nothing is added to the server. When I use this api call in postman. I add a header with the key "auth-token" and for the value the actual token. In body I add a key "file" and add the picture with the button.

Comment: I've been debugging for some time now, but i can't  figure it out. It keeps giving me: 12-12 06:51:40.290 D/TAG     ( 8794): Post: BadRequest : False
12-12 06:51:40.290 D/TAG     ( 8794): Post: RanToCompletion. Also the response stays at null: https://gyazo.com/03a6aab63398869fd230e63075cfe855

Comment: I may be able to get the logs but it will take some time, this is the code snippet: https://hastebin.com/ewekozunax.http i replaced some sensitive info with x.

Comment: Huray, it works thanks a lot, I struggled a long time with this. Also, how do I retreive the json response ?

Comment: @MeanSmoothie Dang, felt like a debugging session over Twitter, 120 chars at a time ;-) Your server response would be in the `response.Content` (from `var response = await client.PostAsync....`)